# Python extract substring via regex with marker as delimiter

Tags: python, regex

In a textfile

```
1. Notice 
Some text 
End Notice
2. Blabla 
Some other text 
Even more text
3. Notice 
Some more text
End Notice
```

I would like to extract the text from "2. Blabla" and the following text(lines) with regex.

A section as "2. Blabla" might be in the textile several time (as with "1. Notice" etc.).

I tried

```
pattern = r"(\d+\. Blabla[\S\n\t\v ]*?\d+\. )"
re.compile(pattern)
result = re.findall(pattern, text) 
print(result)
```

but it gives me

```
['2. BlaBla\nSome other text\nEven more text\n3. ']
```

How can I get rid of the "3. "?

Comment: You may use `\d+\. Blabla[\S\s]*?(?=^\d+\. )`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VWLoMW/1

Comment: Actually, a `(?m)^\d+\. Blabla[\S\s]*?(?=^\d+\. |\Z)` might be a better bet or the `(?m)^\d+\. Blabla.*(?:\n(?!\d+\.).*)*` that is much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?ms)^\d+\. Blabla.*?(?=^\d+\. |\Z)
```

It will match start of a line, one or more digits, a dot, a space, `Blabla`, and then zero or more chars, as few as possible, till the first occurrence of one or more digits + `.` + space at the start of a line, or end of the whole string.

However, there is a faster expression:

```py
(?m)^\d+\. Blabla.*(?:\n(?!\d+\.).*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cPtir9/2/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a line (due to `re.M` option in the Python code)
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `Blabla` - a fixed string
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\n(?!\d+\.).*)*` - any zero or more lines that do not start with one or more digits and then a `.` char.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Wx0YEo):

```py
import re
text = "1. Notice \nSome text \nEnd Notice\n2. Blabla \nSome other text \nEven more text\n3. Notice \nSome more text\nEnd Notice"
pattern = r"^\d+\. Blabla.*(?:\n(?!\d+\.).*)*"
result = re.findall(pattern, text, re.M) 
print(result)
# => ['2. Blabla \nSome other text \nEven more text']
```

Comment: This is better than the option given in the comment above as it still matches if there is nothing after the "2. Blabla" block:

Regex from comment not working: https://regex101.com/r/fb4W4B/1
This one working: https://regex101.com/r/jzbew6/1